# 1.5d Engine need pointers

Tags: c#, xna

[image]

So I'm gonna start on a new project and were surfing around google images and found this image. Basically its almost pure 2D where there is no 3d object and everything is represented in 2d images as you see. Im wondering what this technique is called? Im guessing its some variant of parallax? I know this style has been called 2.5d back in the day. The project will be in MonoGame(c#) so i need headers of where to start developing an engine like this, what is the "2.5d" technique called?

Comment: You can use parallax scrolling to implement a sort of 2.5D effect, but it's not clear that that is precisely what this game was doing. There are other techniques that games like Doom, Marathon, Wolfenstein, etc used as well you can look up. Questions about how to get started or soliciting for "tips and advice" aren't considered on-topic here, but you could ask over at [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).